# swizzle/modify array access

Tags: c++

I have an array of bytes that I want to change how it's accessed. Here's the array:

```
char bytes[100];
```

I want to have another array that changes how the original array is accessed. If we could put references in array, it would look something like this:

```
char& bytes_ref[50];
for(size_t i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    bytes_ref[i] = bytes[i * 2];
}
```

Though array of references aren't valid. I came up with this that in theory does what I want:

```
#include <iostream>
struct Byte {
    char* ref;

    Byte(){}

    Byte(char& c){
        ref = &c;
    }

    operator char&() const {
        return *ref;
    }
};

int main(){
    char bytes[100];
    Byte bytes_ref[50];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        bytes_ref[i] = bytes[i * 2];
    }
}
```

Though this works like I want it to, it takes up a ton of space.

Is there some way to do this without using up 7 more bytes per entry? My instinct is no, but I'm hopeful there may be some kind of special functionality in C++ that could do this, or maybe do some direct memory manipulation and access.

The reason I want to do this is I have an array of bytes that represent an image in NV21 format. I want to create a separate array that references the bytes in the original buffer but takes half the pixels, effectively resizing the image on the fly.

I have to pass a char** to an uncontrolled library.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you use a `std::array` in 1st place?

Comment: You can use an array (or *better* `std::array` or `std::vector`) of `std::reference_wrapper<char>` to get a new "view" of the existing array without modifying it.

Comment: You can always just define an logical array object with a suitable `operator[]`, if the goal is to use the `[i]` notation to access every other byte. But that focus on a particular notation seems suspect. Why do you want that notation?

Comment: Why create a separate array? Just write `arr[i * 2]` where you have `arr[i]` now.

Comment: Sorry everyone. I forgot to mention that I don't have control of the library that I'll be passing the array to. And that I have to pass the array as a pointer. That's a pretty big thing to forget. My bad.

Comment: Many stl containers (including `vector` and `array`) have a `.data()` method which returns a pointer to the first element in the collection, which you can pass to your library in the same way you'd pass a pointer to the first element in your array. Also, I'd just use a second array defining the view, or mapping, between indices. You're still doubling the amount of storage required, but it's better than 8x. (Or just re-order the original array in-place before passing it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can use less memory than one pointer per element

If you need to pass an array of `char*` to an uncontrolled library, I understand that you have to allocate the whole array because that is what the library is expecting. The code would like:

```
std::array<char*, 50> bytes_ref;
for(size_t i = 0; i < bytes_ref.size(); ++i){
    bytes_ref[i] = &bytes[i * 2];
}
```

Then, you can pass the array as:

```
f(bytes_ref.data());
```

If you would not need to use `char**`, you would have more options. You may use `std::reference_wrapper` although its size is similar to a pointer. If you always have to skip 2 elements, you may create an object for this. For example:

```
class Wrapper {
public:
    Wrapper(char *origin) : m_origin(origin) {}
    char* operator[](size_t index) {return m_origin + 2*index;}
private:
    char *m_origin;
};
```

The above will return a pointer to every 2 elements using the [] operator.